# When can a matrix be written as $UDU^H$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have read a solution to the problem of diagonalizing a matrix $A$.

The solution started with the observation "note that $A^H=A$ thus we can diagnalize like this $A=UDU^H$ where $U$ is a unitary matrix and $D$ a diagonal matrix.

I thought that the correct implications to draw was: if $A$ is normal (i.e. $A^HA=AA^H$, then we can diagnalize like this $A=UDU^H$.

What implications are true here? One or both?

(Note to self: 11Losn20140228)

Comment: $A$ is a hermitian matrix and then in particular it's a normal matrix so the two implications are true.

Comment: So, hermitian ⇒ normal ⇒ $UDU^H$ (loose with notation here)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the solution you read is *not* suggesting that all unitarily diagonalisable matrices are precisely those Hermitian matrices. Instead, a Hermitian matrix $A$ is given in the problem and the solution is merely saying that every Hermitian matrix is unitarily diagonalisable.

Since Hermitian matrices form a subset of normal matrices, both you and the solution you read are correct.

As a side note, please be reminded that if $A=UDU^H$, then $A=A^H$ if and only if $D$ is real. That is, Hermitian matrices are not only unitarily diagonalisable, they are also unitarily diagonalisable to *real* diagonal matrices. Put it another way, among all normal matrices, only Hermitian matrices possess entirely real spectra.